# Scipy Euclidean distance between two points

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-spatial

The below code for calculating the Euclidean distance between two points returns `[[9.]]` :

```
from scipy import spatial
d1 = [[11 , 3]]
d2 = [[2 , 3]]
print(spatial.distance.cdist(d1 , d2 ,  "euclidean"))
```

But the Euclidean distance between these two points is 3?

Has the Euclidean distance been implemented correctly?

Comment: `11-2=9`... really.

Comment: Both points have the same y-coordinate of 3, so the line joining the points is horizontal, and its length is the difference between the x-coordinates, i.e. 11-2=9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for Euclidean distance is the following:
dist((x, y), (a, b)) = √((x - a)² + (y - b)²)

Which gives:
= √((11 - 2)² + (3 - 3)²) = √(9)² = 9

Answer (score 1):

The Distance is 9. Euclidian distance is root of sum of **squared differences**. So you have sqrt( (11-2)^2 ) which is sqrt( 9^2 ) which is 9